What is preventing AKS from pulling images from ACR?
I'm using Bicep to create an AKS cluster and connect it to an existing ACR:
param clusterName string = 'MyTestCluster'

param location string = resourceGroup().location

param acrName string = 'mytestacr'

param sshRSAPublicKey string

resource aksCluster 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters@2023-10-01' = {
  name: clusterName
  location: location
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  sku: {
    name: 'Base'
    tier: 'Standard'
  }
  properties: {
    dnsPrefix: dnsPrefix
    agentPoolProfiles: [
      {
        name: 'agentpool'
        osDiskSizeGB: 30
        count: 1
        vmSize: 'standard_d2s_v3'
        osType: 'Linux'
        mode: 'System'
      }
    ]
    linuxProfile: {
      adminUsername: 'azureuser'
      ssh: {
        publicKeys: [
          {
            keyData: sshRSAPublicKey
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    networkProfile: {
      loadBalancerSku: 'standard'
      networkPlugin: 'azure'
      networkPluginMode: 'overlay'
      networkDataplane: 'azure'
      networkPolicy: 'azure'
    }
  }
}

resource acr 'Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries@2021-09-01' existing = {
  name: acrName
  scope: resourceGroup()
}

// Assign the AKS cluster access to the ACR
resource acrRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2020-04-01-preview' = {
  name: guid(acr.id, aksCluster.id, '7f951dda-4ed3-4680-a7ca-43fe172d538d')
  scope: acr
  properties: {
    roleDefinitionId: resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', '7f951dda-4ed3-4680-a7ca-43fe172d538d') // ACR Pull
    principalId: aksCluster.identity.principalId
    principalType: 'ServicePrincipal'
  }
}

The cluster creates correctly and I can see the the cluster has been granted AcrPull on the existing repository.
However when I deploy the following to the cluster, the pull with ImagePullBackOff and 401 Unauthorised from the repository:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myaksapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myaksapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myaksapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myaksapp
        image: mytestacr.azurecr.io/myaksapp:latest
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "256Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

Have I missed a step in the process? If I create the same cluster with
az aks create --resource-group myResourceGroup --name MyTestCluster --node-count 1 --generate-ssh-keys --attach-acr mytestacr

the everything deploys fine as expected.

Could you please edit your question and post the full error message?

There's no error message as such, the pod just goes into pending with status ImagePullBackOff

Are you creating a POD with an image from ACR using the YAML file?

Yes. The deployment YAML file above references an image in mytestacr which I link the cluster to in the Bicep file
